# AMP HTML - persistent dismissal of banner in AMP?

Tags: html, amp-html, hugo

I am using gohugo-amp theme in a hugo app. In the header, I have a banner I want to dismiss onclick and have the dismissed state stored.

I have tried `<a class="page-banner__close" on="tap:page-banner.hide">X</a>` however the banner returns when the page is refreshed.

I have also tried using `<amp-user-notification>` tag. But `<amp-user-notification>` fixes the banner in the footer.

Is there a way to put a dismissible banner in the header and have that dismissed state stored so it does not return upon refresh??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the `amp-user-notifcation` component to be placed at the top by adding this to your CSS:

```
amp-user-notification {
  top: 0;
  bottom: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly in my dev tools. Not so much in my css. I should be able to figure it out now.

Comment: You might need to add a custom rule/id to increase the priority of your adjustment.

Comment: I added id and class. It still doesn't work which is strange because we're only using class for everything else.